# Back button renew?

Tags: objective-c

For a app i need to renew the screen once you've clicking the back button. Let me ex.

On the first screen of the app you've a button (start) and a score. But after the game is done (game over) a new screen appears.

But after clicking on the back button (screen 2) the score is still there. I want a sort of renew of screen after clicking on the back button on screen 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set the labels to:

```
self.count = @"";
```

in the ViewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

Look at viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It should get called on the viewController that you navigate back to.